# How to map a dataset of filenames to a dataset of file contents

Tags: tensorflow

For example, I have a tensorflow dataset where each element is a `tf.string` `Tensor` represents a filename of an image file. Now I want to map this filename dataset to a dataset of image content Tensors.

I wrote code like this, but it doesn't work because map function can't execute eagerly. (Raises an error saying Tensor type has no attribute named numpy.)

```
def parseline(line):
    filename = line.numpy()
    image = some_library.open_image(filename).to_numpy()
    return image

dataset = dataset.map(parseline)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it can be done the following way:

```
path = 'path_to_images'

files = [os.path.join(path, i) for i in os.listdir(path)] # If you need to create a list of filenames, because tf functions require tensors

def parse_image(filename):
    file = tf.io.read_file(filename) # this will work only with filename as tensor
    image = tf.image.decode_image(f)
    return img

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
dataset = dataset.map(parse_image).batch(1)
```

if you're in eager mode just iterate over dataset

```
 for i in dataset:           
    print(i)
```

If not, you'll need an iterator

```
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
with tf.Session as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
```

Comment: Yes, there is tf.image.decode_image. But what if I want to deal with audio files or any other files that have to be processed with external libraries?

Comment: you can try https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io, in some cases i guess decode_raw will do. there used to be `tf.contrib.ffmpeg.encode_audio` but it's deprecated. But there was some alternative method of dealing with such cases