# Keras2 ImageDataGenerator or TensorFlow tf.data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

With Keras2 being implemented into TensorFlow and TensorFlow 2.0 on the horizon, should you use Keras `ImageDataGenerator`  with e.g, `flow_from_directory` or `tf.data` from TensorFlow which also can be used with `fit_genearator` of Keras now?

Will both methods will have their place by serving a different purpose or will `tf.data` be the new way to go and Keras generators deprecated in the future?

Thanks, I would like to take the path which keeps me up to date a bit longer in this fast moving field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 2022

On visiting the [`ImageDataGenerator` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator), there is now a deprecation message that says the following:

> **Deprecated:** [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) is not recommended for new code. Prefer loading images with [`tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) and transforming the output [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) with preprocessing layers. For more information, see the tutorials for [loading images](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) and [augmenting images](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation), as well as the [preprocessing layer guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers).

Answer (score 19):

Alongside custom defined Python generators, you can wrap the `ImageDataGenerator` from Keras inside `tf.data`.

`TensorFlow >= 2.10` (it's all about `tf.data.Dataset()`)

```
   # Treat it as a normal tf.data.Dataset()
   dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory (...)
   # Or any other augmentation
   normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
   normalized_dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
```

`TensorFlow <= 2.9` (deprecation warnings may already appear in those)
The following snippets are taken from the TensorFlow 2.0 documentation.

```
img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, rotation_range=20)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    img_gen.flow_from_directory, args=[flowers], 
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), 
    output_shapes = ([32,256,256,3],[32,5])
)
```

Therefore, one can still use the typical Keras `ImageDataGenerator`, you just need to wrap it into a `tf.data.Dataset` like above.

Comment: This is really the best of both world!

Comment: Yes, I am also of the same opinion. At least the swicth to TF 2.0 is done step by step.

Comment: Dear Calin, that is great news. I think they noticed how valuable ImageDataGenerator was/is. Thanks

Comment: @TimbusCalin correct me if I'm wrong, but in order to make use of TFX, we would still need to convert the df.data.Dataset to a TFRecords file in the TF.Example format per https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/examplegen?  What is the best approach for this?  Essentially, I am converting an image model built using Keras' ImageDataGenerator to TF2 and want to make use of TFX components as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Since its release, TensorFlow Dataset API is a default recommended way to construct input pipeline for any model build on TensorFlow backend, both Keras and low-level TensorFlow. 
In later versions of TF 1.xx it can be directly used in `tf.keras.Model.fit` method as

```
model.fit(dataset, epochs)
```

It's good both for rapid prototyping,

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train, test))
dataset = dataset.shuffle().repeat().batch()
```

And for building complex, high performance ETL pipelines 
4. Upgrade your data input pipelines, more on this here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets

As per official docs, in TF 2.0 it'll also be the default way to input data to the model. https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/migration_guide

As by default, upcoming TensorFlow version will be executed eagerly, dataset object will become iterable and will be even easier to use.

Comment: Thank you sharky, also for the edit of my post. So it can be said that keras Generators will be replaced by tf.data, correct? Cheers

Comment: Although we can't say this for sure, I think that it will be eventually replaced. Keras preprocessing is a little outdated. It was built as a simpler alternative to TF's queue runners. But now tf.data is just as simple to use, and has more potential functionality. So if you know how to use tf.data, there's no need to use other methods

Comment: Cheers. One additional question, I know from Keras that you can easily import data from folder structures. Everything is kind of automated. I looked into tf.data and it seem much more manual effort. Did I just not look correctly or are the tf functions less automated? thanks again for your explanations

Comment: It's easy. `from_tensor_slices` can accept list of filenames as argument. then just apply `dataset.map` with any preprocessing you need. See my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332476/how-to-map-a-dataset-of-filenames-to-a-dataset-of-file-contents/55338390#55338390

Comment: Sharky you are the best. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

For me, I prefer to build a generator with `yield`:

```
def generator(batch_size=4,path):
imgs=glob(path+'*.jpg')
while True:
    batch=[]
    for i in range(batch_size):
        idx=np.random.randint(0,len(imgs))
        img=cv.resize(cv.imread(imgs[idx]),(256,256))/255
        batch.append(img)
    batch=np.array(batch)
    yield batch
```

Then create the generator and input it to `model.fit_generator`, it will work.

You can choose data randomly like this or use some recurrent methods.

Though the code is rough, it is easy to change so that it can generate complex batch.

Note that this is a way to generate for TF 1.X with Keras2 and not with TensorFlow 2.0.

Comment: For TF 2.X, just wrap your generator with Dataset.from_generator (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator)